# Pase de imagenes en html cada cierto tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen

a ver si me podéis echar un cable. Estoy haciendo una página web y quiero hacer que se vayan pasando imagenes cada x tiempo.
Lo que tengo ahora mismo es:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
miBanner = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = miBanner.getContext("2d");


var i=0;
var imagenes = ["./img/banner1.jpeg","./img/banner2.jpg","./img/banner3.png"];
img = new Image ();


function dibujar(){ 
    img.src = imagenes[0];
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 900, 260);

    if(i<2){
        i++;
    }
    else{
        i=0;}
    }//dibujar()

setInterval(dibujar,300);
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

Pero se queda la imagen estática. A ver si me podéis decir el fallo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te hice una pequeña demo, lo cierto es no he utilizado canvas, pero te puede servir como base, aunque no cambia mucho si lo haces con el canvas.

HTML:

```
<img id="to_show" src="" width="300px" heigth="300px" alt="">
```

JS:

```
var pos=0;
var to_show = document.getElementById('to_show');
var imagenes = 
['https://www.google.es/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png','http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg'];


function dibujar(pos ){
    //Cada vez que se llama esta funcion, vamos mostrando la imagen de la posicion que nos pasa.
    to_show.src = imagenes[pos-1];
}


var to = setInterval(function(){
    pos++;
    dibujar(pos);
  //SI la variable que vamos incrementando es igual que la longitud de nuestro array, limpiamos el intervalo.
  if(pos == imagenes.length){
    clearInterval(to);
  }
},1000);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1cjtxpn1/10/)

Comment: lo probaré también de tu forma, parece fácil. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada y como dice @bercklyn Carlosviza el fallo era que solo mostrabas la imagen en la posición de 0.